# Accessing data within New Order email

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, order-email

For the past couple of days I have been attempting to access the `$payment` object in my `new_order` email. My objective is to display the credit card type along with the last four digits of card used to purchase the item. I know that once the payment object has been obtained/set to a variable, it comes with a method `getCcType()`. I have attempted to obtain this through multiple variations, but for whatever reason I cannot access it.

My question would be what file would I need to go to in order to set the payment variable so that it can be accessed within the `new order` email? The same way I can access and use order, `{{var order.created_at | date: "%b %d, %y"}}` and `{{var order.getIncrementId()}}`.

I found teh `OrderSender.php` file and believe this is the file where my variables are getting set.. such as: `order`, `payment_html`, `formattedShippingAddress` so that they can be used: `{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}` and `{{var payment_html|raw}}`.

Any help or enlightenment on how I can approach this will be greatly appreciated. I am brand new to magento and php so it feels a little foreign.